# firebug error - what does this mean?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using the jquerymobile platform with one of my Drupal sites. It works flawlessly on my dev server, but on the live server, every time I click on a link it sticks a pound sign in and refuses to load the content of the page being linked. When I hit the browser's refresh button, the pound sign goes away, and the content does load.

Example:

```
<a href="/sponsors">Sponsors</a>
```

should go to http://mysite.com/sponsors. What happens on my live site is http://mysite.com/#/sponsors. The page stalls there, but if I click reload, the # goes away and the content loads.

I have a user agent switcher in firefox, so I turned firebug on, and on the live site, I'm getting the following error every time I click a link:

"attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope"

This does not occur on the dev site. The live site is http://m.shoppersummit.com/. Any ideas why this would happen? As far as I can tell, I have the same version of jquery, jqueryui, and jquerymobile installed.

**Edited to address redirect loop**
I've been at work since 6:30 AM; my brain is fried. This is a drupal site, with a "real" theme and a mobile theme. The only way to view the mobile theme (which is where the error is occurring) in a desktop browser is to change your user agent string to a mobile one. There's a firefox addon that will do this. If you try to view the site with a standard desktop user agent string, you will get the redirect.

Comment: Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects. http://m.shoppersummit.com//shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com/shoppersummit.com

Comment: Thanks. I don't get that error. I also don't know how it's happening, since the codebase is identical to what's on our dev server. Any thoughts?

Comment: Oops. Forgot something that deals with that; editing OP.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including a target? e.g. target="_self"

Comment: That doesn't make a difference, and in some places actually breaks things that were working.

Comment: When I navigate to the link above, I get a redirect loop error. I get  the feeling that JQuery is expecting another parameter.

Comment: It was just a thought, I was thinking that your code is looking for an anchor tag or Jquery is looking for ID element(which is missing). If the browser was just acting quirky the I thought adding 'target=' would help. If the link above is rendered from code then you might want to edit your question and add that code.